# Propensity Score Matching and significance of estimators in logit regression

Tags: statistical-significance, logit, propensity-scores

If I run a logistic regression to calculate a propensity score (i.e. the dependent variable is 0= do not participate in the treatment; 1= do participate) and therefore I want to see the probability a variable affects participation, shouldn't I get non significant effect of my independent variables?

If my independent variables prove to be significant, doesn't that mean that there is a bias between my treated group and control group?

Thank you !

Comment: If the independent variables are significant, then they are associated with the outcome. If the indepedent variables are not significant then they are not statistically associated with the outcome. However there could still be some association. That is why you check to see if the propensity scores are balance among the treatment and control groups.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is what I thought. But I saw different examples with significant predictors without balance test. I think I got it now, thanks again